# how to get data in pivot control to move to top half of screen?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have this pivot control :

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0,104,0,229" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid Height="800" Width="468">
            <phone:Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentHeaderItemsSearch}">
                <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ProcessName" Text="{Binding ProcessName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="48" Margin="2,20,2,2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>      

                <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>                   
                    <DataTemplate>                          
                            <Grid x:Name="Content"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,-35,0,0">
                            <Viewbox x:Name="viewboxHeader"  Tag="0">
                                <Grid Height="80" Width="436">
                                    <Canvas Background="{Binding Urgency, Converter={StaticResource converttocolor}}" Margin="0,0,409,0">
                                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Duration}" Foreground="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"  Canvas.Top="25" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Width="80" Height="28" Canvas.Left="-26" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                                <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90"/>
                                            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DocDesc}" Foreground="White" Margin="31,4,0,44" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyBold}"/>
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Originator}" Margin="31,44,167,4" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}"/>
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DocDate, Converter={StaticResource convertshortdate}}" Margin="277,44,0,4" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Grid>                         
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>

            </phone:Pivot>  

        </Grid>


    </ScrollViewer>
```

so here is the result I get when I run the app and use search function :

[image]

How am I going to get that Object that shows the result to show just right under the that pivot item heading "76"?

I am using visual studio 2012, c#, silverlight, windows phone 8, and i am using a pivot control here for the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does changing the top level item in the DataTemplate to a StackPanel does that? Or does Setting the Grid's VerticalContentAlignment=Top and setting VerticalAlignment=Top/Stretch work? You can either be greedy and use all the space in the PivotItem.ItemTemplate while aligning top, or be proactively space conscious and align to top.

Also, during your tests you should consider dropping the top level Grid margin property as it might be specifying to the XAML parser you want the Grid to take up all the space in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: thanks for this insight! as i changed these setting it moved to the top but with a gap, i then realized i had an unwanted viewbox populating this area so i took it out and moved to just under the header item! sorry for late post :P